# Django formtools with custom template

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I have the following custom wizard

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="smartwizard">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#step-1">Engagement Setup<br /><small>Basic info</small></a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-2">File Upload<br /><small>Upload files</small></a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-3">Business Rules<br /><small>rules</small></a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-4">Documentation<br /><small>documentation</small></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div id="step-1" class="">
                <div id="form-step-0" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Code <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Write your code" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
....
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

I have setup the django form as such

```
class PageOne(forms.Form):
    ibs_code = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    engagement_name  = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    engagement_manager = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    engagement_partner = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    solution =  forms.CharField(label='What solution would you like to use?', widget=forms.Select(choices=FRUIT_CHOICES))
```

And of course the views..

```
class TestWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(
        location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'temp_uploads'))


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.is_done = False

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.is_done:
            # return [self.templates['done']]
            return [TEMPLATES['done']]
        else:
            return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
     .....
     ......
```

Now I want to use the custom template with the form. Meaning, I want to generate the form fields the way the html/style looks with `form-group` and such. How can I achieve this?

I tried the [documentation](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#advanced-namedurlwizardview-methods) but they weren't any sources for custom templating

**Update #1**: Doing something like this is not sufficient

```
 <div id="form-step-0" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">
        {% if wizard.form.forms %}
            {{wizard.form.management_form }}
            {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                {{form}}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            {{ wizard.form }}
        {% endif %}
     </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

I need it to look just like the html I put together

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can specify the `class` to be used for your form fields, for example:

```
class PageOne(forms.Form):
    ibs_code = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class' : 'YourClassName'}
        )
    )
```

Second, you can put the individual fields within the template as you want

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="smartwizard">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#step-1">Engagement Setup<br /><small>Basic info</small></a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-2">File Upload<br /><small>Upload files</small></a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-3">Business Rules<br /><small>rules</small></a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-4">Documentation<br /><small>documentation</small></a></li>
        </ul>
        <form>
            {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
            {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div id="step-1" class="">
                <div id="form-step-0" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Code <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                        {{ form.ibs_code }}
                        {{ form.ibs_code.errors }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
....

       </div>
       </form>


    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

**EDIT - ACTUAL LIVE EXMAPLE**

```
        <form id="" class="max-width-800px margin-center" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {{ wizard.form.media }}
            <input name="job-is_user" type="checkbox" hidden {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}checked{% endif %}>
            <input name="job-is_company" type="checkbox" hidden {% if request.user.company_user %}checked{% endif %}>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_job-plan_"PLANS[0].id >Job Listing Type</label>
                {{ wizard.form.plan }}
                <div class="alert alert-primary top-3">Jobs are subscription-based and are active until you've filled the position.  At the end of your recurring billing cycle you will be charged and your listing will be moved back to the top of its category.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label for="id_job-title">Job Title</label>
                    {{ wizard.form.title }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label for="id_job-category">Job Category</label>
                    <span class="form-select">
                        {{ wizard.form.category }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Job Type</label>
                <div class="row">
                    {% for employment in EMPLOYMENTS %}
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <span class="form-radio form-radio-lg">
                            <input type="radio" id="id_job-employment_{{employment.id}}" name="job-employment" value="{{ employment.id }}" required {% if job.employment.id == employment.id or wizard.form.employment.value|add:"0" == employment.pk %}checked{% endif %}>
                            <label for="id_job-employment_{{employment.id}}">{{ employment }}</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label for="id_job-job_level">Job Level</label>
                    <span class="form-select">
                        {{ wizard.form.job_level }}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label for="id_job-salary_range">Job Compensation</label>
                    <span class="form-select">
                        {{ wizard.form.salary_range }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="job-location-groupX" class="form-group">
                <label for="id_job-office_base">Job Location</label>
                <div class="row">
                    {% for office in OFFICE_BASE %} 
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="form-radio form-radio-lg">
                            <input type="radio" id="id_job-office_base_{{office.id}}" name="job-office_base" value="{{ office.id }}" {% if job.office_base.id == office.id or wizard.form.office_base.value|add:"0" == office.pk %}checked{% endif %}>
                            <label for="id_job-office_base_{{office.id}}">{{ office.name }}</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div id="new-job-location-details" class="hidden top-1">
                    {{ wizard.form.outside_location }}
                    {{ wizard.form.outside_location.errors }}
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-increase-spacing">
                        <li>
                            <span class="form-checkbox">
                                {{ wizard.form.relocation_assistance }}
                                <label id="label-id_job-relocation_assistance" for="id_job-relocation_assistance">Relocation assistance provided</label>
                                {{ wizard.form.relocation_assistance.errors }}

                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="form-checkbox">
                                {{ wizard.form.visa_sponsorship }}
                                <label for="id_job-visa_sponsorship">Visa sponsorship provided</label>
                                {{ wizard.form.visa_sponsorship.errors }}
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_job-description">Job Description</label>
                <div class="col-12">
                {{ wizard.form.description }}
                {{ wizard.form.description.errors }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="job-how-to-apply-groupX" class="form-group">
                <label>How to Apply to This Job</label>
                <div class="row">               
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="form-radio form-radio-lg">
                            <input type="radio" required id="new-job-apply-us" value="4" name="job-apply_online" {% if job.apply_online == 4 or wizard.form.apply_online.value|add:"0" == 4 %}checked {% endif %}>
                            <label for="new-job-apply-us">Through us <em class="float-right tablet-hide">(recommended)</em></label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <span class="form-radio form-radio-lg">
                            <input type="radio" id="new-job-apply-you" name="job-apply_online" value="3" {% if job.apply_online == 3 or wizard.form.apply_online.value|add:"0" == 3 %}checked {% endif %}>
                            <label for="new-job-apply-you">Through you <em class="float-right tablet-hide">(external URL)</em></label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="new-job-apply-details" class="hidden top-1">
                    {{ wizard.form.apply_url }}
                    {{ wizard.form.howto_apply }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="job-extras" class="form-group">
                <h6>Additional Extras <span class="optional-field">(optional)</span></h6>
                {{ wizard.form.addons }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-solid-teal">{% if request.user.company_user %}Preview Your Listing{% elif request.user.is_authenticated %}Enter Company Details{% else %}User Details{% endif %} &rarr;</button>
        </form>
```

forms.py

```
class JobPostWizardForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = "alert alert-error"
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category.objects.all(), empty_label='Choose one...', required=False)
    job_level = forms.ModelChoiceField(JobLevel.objects.all(), empty_label='Choose one...', required=False)
    salary_range = forms.ModelChoiceField(Salary.objects.active(), empty_label='Choose one...', required=False)
    plan = forms.ModelChoiceField(Plan.objects.all(), empty_label=None, required=True, widget=PlanSelect)
    is_user = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    is_company = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [
            'plan','title','category','employment','job_level','salary_range','office_base', 'outside_location',
            'relocation_assistance','visa_sponsorship','description','apply_online','howto_apply','addons', 'is_user',
            'is_company', 'apply_url'
            ]

    def __init__(self, is_active= False, edit_mode=False, plan=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['plan'].initial = Plan.objects.all()[plan]
        if is_active : self.fields['plan'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True

        self.fields['description'].required = True
        self.fields['apply_url'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'External URL'
        self.fields['howto_apply'].widget = forms.Textarea()
        self.fields['howto_apply'].widget.attrs['rows']=10
        self.fields['howto_apply'].widget.attrs['placeholder']="Additional instructions..."

        self.fields['relocation_assistance'].widget = AuthenticJobsCheckbox()
        self.fields['visa_sponsorship'].widget = AuthenticJobsCheckbox()

        self.fields['addons'].widget = AddOnCheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['addons'].queryset = AddOnItem.objects.filter(active=True)
        #if edit_mode : self.fields['addons'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
        if is_active : self.fields['addons'].widget.attrs['onclick'] = "return false;"
        self.error_class = DivErrorList
```

Comment: Good approach! Mind if I reach out for additional question?

Comment: What is the additional question?

Comment: Using your solution I am getting ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered.']. Ideas?

Comment: Try adding `{{ wizard.form.media }}`

Comment: Tried, but keeps showing the error. Added before or after?

Comment: added a full live example